# Revisions gives "Date not found"

Tags: laravel-backpack

I followed the guidelines to make Revisions work, here: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.6/crud-operation-revisions

I then cleared cache and route cache, then restart my artisan server. 
I can get the revisions button, but when I try to view my revisions, I get this error (MYLARAVELPATH is my local path):

Class 'Date' not found (View: /MYLARAVELPATH/vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/inc/revision_timeline.blade.php) (0)
Class 'Date' not found (0)

I see that data have been stored correctly into the revisions table, and I don't have any other issues.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a `Date` alias in your `config/app.php` file like this:

```
'aliases' => [
    // current entries...
    'Date' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Date::class,

],
```